# PDO displaying data from database foreach specific ID

Tags: php, pdo

if member logon they have url like index.php?id=5

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

I can show the user data by doing this

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = "5" ORDER BY tgl DESC';                    
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
     echo '<td>'. $row['tgl'] . '</td>';    
}
```

but if i change to this, nothing happen.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = $id ORDER BY tgl DESC');    
$q->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

foreach ($pdo->query($q) as $row) {
    echo '<td>'. $row['tgl'] . '</td>';
}
```

but i dont understand.
can somebody help me please? give me right code and explain it please, iam new with PDO.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement you are using a prepared query, therefore your query should look different:

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = :id ORDER BY tgl DESC');
```

You also have to execute your query after you bind the parameters, like so:

```
$q->execute();.
```

So doing this should fix your problem:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = :id ORDER BY tgl DESC');
$q->execute(['id'=>$id])                   
foreach ($q as $row) {
  echo '<td>'. $row['tgl'] . '</td>';    
}
```

It is generally better practice to use prepared statements as they prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: wow, this "Single quote string don't get evaluated by PHP", i will carefully now about quote, i forget that. many thanks

Comment: There is a lot of traffic here from Google. The opening poster is long gone, and we have to think about those people from Google. I volunteered to edit this answer in order to make the code follow the recommendation to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use the `query` function, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php, with `prepare`, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php. `Prepare` goes with `execute`, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php. You also need to put the binded name in the query.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = :id ORDER BY tgl DESC');    
$q->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
while($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<td>'. $row['tgl'] . '</td>';
}
```

or

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = ? ORDER BY tgl DESC');
$q->execute(array($id));
while($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<td>'. $row['tgl'] . '</td>';
}
```

Both methods are prepared statements. They separate the user's data so it won't cause issues with your query.

Also, as the other answers have alluded to if you used double quotes your second query would have executed...but don't do that it opens you to injections. Here's how you could have done that but the prepared are better. Also note the casting of the `$id` to an int which forces it to be a number.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = $id ORDER BY tgl DESC";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
     echo '<td>'. $row['tgl'] . '</td>';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes treating variables as string in your code

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = $id ORDER BY tgl DESC';
```

have to be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id_member = $id ORDER BY tgl DESC";
```

or you will recieve $id instead of it's value;